# O365, Manage Distribution List group with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, exchange-server

Hope you're having a great day so far!
I'm using O365 Online, and I'm trying to Add a user to a distribution list group with Powershell, to automate user creation.
here are my steps

1. Connect to MolService : `Connect-MsolService`
2. I get the `ObjectID` of the distribution group.

   `$GroupeID = Get-MsolGroup -ObjectId $SupervisorGroup.ObjectId`
3. I get the user ObjectID

`ObjectIDUser =  Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $user.ObjectId`

4. I'm adding the user to the group

`Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $GroupeID.ObjectId -GroupMemberObjectId $Object.ObjectId -GroupMemberType User`

But here is the error:

```
Add-MsolGroupMember : You cannot update mail-enabled groups using this cmdlet. Use Exchange Online to perform 
this operation.
At line:11 char:2
+  Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $GroupeID.ObjectId -GroupMemberOb ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-MsolGroupMember], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MailEnabledGroupsNotSupportedException 
   ,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.AddGroupMember
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states: You cannot use the MSOL Cmdlets with Mail Enabled Objects, Use the Exchange Online Cmdlets for that:

Here's an helper function to load the Office 365 Exchange Cmdlets:

```
Function Load-365ExchangeShell
{
Param(
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
$Cred
)
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -DisableNameChecking
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Load-365ExchangeShell -Cred $Cred
```

Then use the relevant cmdlet ([Add-DistributionGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps)):

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "DistributionGroupID_here" -Member "UserToAddID_here"
```

> Note: for future use you better use the Updated Exchange Online V2
> Module instead of the above method, as the old commands are
> deprecated...

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)